# Where can I find a list of un-patched CVEs for a specific piece of software?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities

Is there a database of vulnerabilities somewhere, that can be queried in such a way as to return results for all non-patched vulnerabilities for a specific piece of software?

For example, I would like to see a list of the current non-patched (workarounds don't count as patches) vulnerabilities, including CVE numbers, in Windows 7.

Comment: @Paul - Having a CVE number does *not*, by definition, mean it is solved.  A fully-patched Windows box will still have numerous vulnerabilities, all *with CVE numbers*, that do not yet have patches released.  The only thing a CVE number represents is that it is a known vulnerability in the Common Vulnerabilities & Exposures list.

Comment: @Paul - For example, CVE-2008-4609 is a vulnerability in the TCP/IP stack affecting almost all Windows OS's since Win2K. Microsoft rates it "Critical" or "Important" for most versions. McAfee Vulnerability Manager marks it as a "Medium" finding. US-CERT rates it "High".  However, Microsoft has not (and will not - see Security Bulletin MS09-048) released any patches to mitigate this in XP or 2K. This may be a somewhat-poor example of what I'm looking for (I'm more aiming at zero-day vulnerabilities) but it's one I encounter often.

Comment: If it is registered as a CVE, it can't really be considered a zero-day anymore, can it?

Comment: @Avid - Okay, you caught me there.  But I'm sure you caught my meaning, too.  I was running out of characters again.

Comment: you are right, Avid's answer is the correct reply that  I should have provided. Nevertheless, I am aware of software companies that does always provide solutions for vulnerabilities known publicly (and have CVE entries), and that mislead my answer. In between, for many software vendors, a work around is a solution at least on the short run. In General If responsible disclosure is respected (which is the case of Secunia) then this means it is un-patched either because the vendor was not quick enough to patch it *but will* or the vendor estimates the cost is higher than the risk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try the National Vulnerability Database (NVD) [advanced search page](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/search), however it is quite slow and isn't great for searching for a specific product.

A faster and more direct service is [CVE Details](http://www.cvedetails.com/product-list.php) which lets you browse CVEs by product.

Finally, you could try downloading [machine-readable CVEs](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/data-feeds) and parsing them yourself.

Answer (score 6):

one good starting point for this would be www.secunia.com.  You can get a list by product there, of known security issues, and the note on the page unpatched issues.  For windows 7 for example, there's [this list](http://secunia.com/advisories/product/27467/)